# Issues with assigning reactive values within reactive functions

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have some issues with assigning values within a reactive function to reactive values. Depending on the input$id I want to assign a value to the correct reactive value. However, I am not able to write the reactive values although I can observe the correct values calling my reactive function for example in an observe environment. Eventually, I want to, depending on input$top, assign input$a1 to reac.val$tab1 and input$a2 to reac.val$tab2.
I attached my ui.R and server.R files below.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(navbarPage("My App", id = "top",
               tabPanel("Infos",  id = "info",
                        textInput("name", "last name", "")),
               navbarMenu("Menu",
                          tabPanel("tab1",
                                   column(3, textInput(inputId="a1", label="input1", value = 0 , width = 100)),
                                   column(4, tableOutput("aim1"))),
                          tabPanel("tab2",
                                   column(3, textInput(inputId="a2", label="input2", value = 0 , width = 100)),
                                   column(4, tableOutput("aim2"))))
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

val <- data.frame(first = numeric(1), second = numeric(1))
reac.val <- reactiveValues("tab1" = val, "tab2" = val)

  observeTab <- reactive({
     tab <- input$top
     if (tab != "Infos") {
        tab.df <- reac.val[[tab]]
        first.val <- as.numeric(input$a1)
        second.val <- as.numeric(input$a2)
        tab.df$tab1 <- first.val
        tab.df$tab2 <- first.val
        reac.val[[tab]] <- tab.df
        reac.val[[tab]] 
     }
})


  output$aim1 <- renderTable({
     reac.val[[input$top]]
  })

  output$aim2 <- renderTable({
     reac.val[[input$top]]
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem that `observeTab`  it s a function , but you call it nowhere

you can try add

```
observe({
    observeTab()
  })
```

in your server, so you call your function in every change.

Or if you want to call fucntion only when tab changed

```
observeEvent(input$top,{
    observeTab()
  })
```

## Typo

And you have typo here ( my mind)

```
tab.df$tab1 <- first.val
tab.df$tab2 <- first.val
```

need

```
tab.df$tab1 <- first.val
tab.df$tab2 <- second.val
```